# In PHPUnit, how do I prevent headers to be sent

Tags: php, session, http-headers, phpunit

I have a test suite in PHPUnit. Some of the tests work with session (regenerate id, start etc). Those tests fails as PHPUnit already echoed something.

I am not really testing what are the headers. Is there a way to prevent headers from being sent in PHP? This is a CLI PHP, not a web server php module.

(The solution I will implement if no other possibility is to build my own "fake" session handler for the unit tests purposes, aka DI, but I rather play with the real session if possible).

Comment: you can start output buffering (ob_start()) before the output to capture the output and allow headers to run without problems. Output then gets sent at the end after all headers.

Comment: I know that, I am hoping to find a way to avoid modifying the PHPUnit code base.

Comment: Try to use https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess

Comment: @sectus why not putting this as an answer?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka , I was not sure about result. And I need to 'expand' from 'link only answer'. :^ )

Comment: @sectus well...I'll write in 3-4 hours if that solves it :-)

Comment: I did that, but now I get the bootstrap file included twice for some reason, so get errors on already defined constants